# How to print a stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack

so for an assignment of mine we have to modify a stack class and test it. I have successfully added all the necessary methods, but what I am stuck on is how best to print out what is in the stack when I demonstrate it. So basically, I'm going to fill the stack with random data and test the various methods I implemented, but I don't know how to print out the stack to the console to show that I've actually done what I'm supposed. I know this is a pretty basic question, but I'm just stuck here. I am guessing I have to use the method getTop somehow, but how to I use that to print what's in the stack. Here are all my files:

StackP.cpp

```
    #include <cassert>

    using namespace std;

     #include "StackP.h"

     Stack::Stack()
        : topPtr(0) {
     }

     Stack::Stack(const Stack& aStack)
        throw(OutOfStorageException) {

        // Original list is empty
        if (aStack.topPtr == 0) {
           topPtr = 0;
        }
        else {
           try {
              // Copy first node
              topPtr = new StackNode;
              topPtr->item = aStack.topPtr->item;

              // Copy rest of list
              StackNode* newPtr = topPtr;    // Pointer to new list 
              for (StackNode* origPtr = aStack.topPtr->next;
                   origPtr != 0;
                   origPtr = origPtr->next) {
                 newPtr->next = new StackNode;
                 newPtr = newPtr->next;
                 newPtr->item = origPtr->item;
              }

             newPtr->next = 0;
           }
           catch (const bad_alloc&) {
           // Release all memory successfully allocated in this copy
              while (!isEmpty() ) {
                pop();
              }
              throw OutOfStorageException("Out of memory");
           }
        }
     }

     Stack::~Stack() {

        // Pop until stack is empty
    while (!isEmpty() ) {                            
       pop();
    }
    assert(topPtr == 0);
 }

 bool Stack::isEmpty() const {

    return topPtr == 0;
 }

 void Stack::push(const StackItemType& newItem)
    throw(OutOfStorageException) {

    try {
       StackNode* newPtr = new StackNode;

       newPtr->item = newItem;

       newPtr->next = topPtr;
       topPtr = newPtr;
    }
    catch (const bad_alloc&) {
       throw OutOfStorageException("Out of memory");
    }
    }
 }

 void Stack::pop()
    throw(OutOfDataException) {

    if (isEmpty() ) {
       throw OutOfDataException("Cannot pop an empty stack.");
    }
    StackNode* temp = topPtr;
    topPtr = topPtr->next;

    temp->next = 0;  // safeguard
    delete temp;
 }

 void Stack::pop(StackItemType& stackTop)
    throw(OutOfDataException) {

    if (isEmpty() ) {
       throw OutOfDataException("Cannot pop an empty stack.");
    }
    stackTop = topPtr->item;
    StackNode* temp = topPtr;
    topPtr = topPtr->next;

    temp->next = 0;  // safeguard
    delete temp;
 }

 void Stack::getTop(StackItemType& stackTop) const
    throw(OutOfDataException) {

    if (isEmpty() ) {
       throw OutOfDataException("Cannot get the top of an empty stack.");
    }
    stackTop = topPtr->item;
 }

  void Stack::popAndDiscard(int count) {

    while (count>0 && !isEmpty()) {

      pop();
      count--;
      }//end while

    }// end popAndDiscard
```

StackP.h:

```
#ifndef STACKP_H
 #define STACKP_H 1

 #include "OutOfStorageException.h"
 #include "OutOfDataException.h"

 typedef int StackItemType;

 class Stack {
 public:

    Stack();

    Stack(const Stack& aStack)
       throw(OutOfStorageException);

    ~Stack();

    bool isEmpty() const;

    void push(const StackItemType& newItem)
       throw(OutOfStorageException);

    void pop()
       throw(OutOfDataException);

    void pop(StackItemType& stackTop)
       throw(OutOfDataException);

    void getTop(StackItemType& stackTop) const
       throw(OutOfDataException);

    void popAndDiscard(int count);


 private:

    struct StackNode {
       StackItemType item;

       StackNode* next;
    };

    StackNode* topPtr;
 };

  #endif
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Generally, you can't inspect a stack unless you're also consuming it. That's its whole point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  For various reasons, the homework tag is discouraged.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reduce your code to the minimum that's necessary to show your problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can have *the stack* do its own inspection on request. I.e. implement a `print(std::ostream& os)` method in your stack class. It owns the head pointer, etc. and you should have not problem writing the code that walks that node list, dumping data long the way.

Answer (score 2):

You should add print function as @WhozCraig suggested:

```
void print(std::ostream& os)
{
    StackNode* current = topPtr;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        os<<current->item<< " ";
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

don't forget to `#include <ostream>`